# Print consonant and vowels

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, io

My assignment is to to create two threads running functions (called vow and cons). The threads take turns printing the respective words of the phrase supplied from a text file. The main thread shouldn't post anything (only cons and vow functions should print). I can't use synchronization primitives such as mutexes for thread coordination. But I can use `yield()`. I think I might have my answer below but I also might be way off and I didn't use yield() at all.

Could someone please take a look and tell me if this meets the requirements I listed above.

---

phrase.txt:

> In computer architecture, multithreading is the ability of a central processing unit (CPU) or a single core in a multi-core processor to execute multiple processes or threads concurrently, appropriately supported by the operating system.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

void cons(std::string currWord){
    std::cout << "cons: " << currWord << "\n";
}

void vow(std::string currWord){
    std::cout << "vow: " << currWord << "\n";
}

bool checkVowel(std::string word) {
    char vowels[10] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(word[0] == vowels[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::string currWord;
    std::ifstream input;
    input.open("phrase.txt");

    if(input.is_open()) {

    currWord = std::string();

    while(!input.eof()) {
            input >> currWord;
        if(checkVowel(currWord)) {
            std::thread vowThread(vow, currWord);
            vowThread.join();
        }
        else {
            std::thread consThread(cons, currWord);
            consThread.join();
        }
    }

    input.close();
    }

    else {
        std::cout << "Error: File not opened";
    }

    return 0;
}

bool checkVowel(std::string);
void vow(std::string);
void cons(std::string);
```

Comment: I believe the assignment excepts you to keep both threads alive for the duration of the program, not create and join them for every word.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't think I have a great understanding on how to go about doing that. I was under the assumption that they were both alive because I didn't think I could call join() more than once. Could you point me somewhere to help me understand this concept better because I am really struggling.

Comment: Can you add the exact assignment? Wording is rather important in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a little confusing.  You're using names like `currWord` and passing a `word` to `checkVowel`, which is then checking for 'aeiou' etc.  I think of vowels as letters, so on the face of it you appear to be checking whole words against individual vowel letters, which probably shouldn't match.  That said, maybe the file is ordered such that it's actually only reading letters at a time.  Either way, your code is unclear.

As has been said in the comments, whilst you've technically used threads to perform the printing, it's unlikely that this is the strategy that was expected to solve the problem.  There are many approaches that you *could* take to solving the problem, one of which might be something like this:

```
start ConThread
start VowelThread

Open File
ForEach word in file
    ForEach letter in word
        if Vowel
            StoreLetter
            Set VowelFlag
        else
            StoreLetter
            Set ConFlag
        while ReadNextLetterFlag not set give up control
        clear ReadNextLetterFlag

Shutdown...
```

The vowel/Con threads then consist of something like:

```
While not shutdown
    While ConFlag not set give up control
    clear ConFlag
    Retrieve letter
    Output to console
    Set ReadNextLetterFlag
```

Giving up control of the running thread could be achieve using `yield` (although this isn't particularly efficient) and you may want to pair it with `sleep`.

For flags, you probably want to look at either `atomic` and/or `volatile` variables.

Comment: Okay, I tried to implement what you suggested above but I am getting errors. It says I am attempting to use a deleted function. I'm adding it to my original question now.

Comment: Also I think I can check whole words at a time instead of characters by using my checkVowel function because it treats the word as an array and checks if it's first letter is a vowel. But that might be a bad idea...?

Comment: @Carl You aren't really supposed to edit your question after you've received an answer, see: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/4203 (also broken code, which is what your current iteration is would be classed as off topic and *may* be more suitable for stack overflow).  As far as the `checkVowel` function goes, what happens if the word is 'fish', the first letter is a consonant, the second is a vowel.  Do you only care what letter the word starts with?

Comment: Heck I'm sorry for doing that. Should I switch it back? Also I am really sorry because yes I only care about the first letter. I'm sorry I didn't make that clear. I really appreciate all of your help. Sorry I have been so confusing. I'll try to be more clear in the future. I really appreciate the time you've taken to help me!

Comment: @Carl I've rolled the edit to the question back already.

Comment: @Carl you can't pass the `word` into the thread on creation, because it will change as you read additional information from the file.  If you haven't already done so, I'd also read up on `atomic` and `volatile` variables, you need to be careful when you're accessing the same variable from different threads.  Also, you'll notice that in my example the thread function loops while not shutdown, as you've written it your functions will only run once, then exit.

Comment: @Carl The error you encountered is probably due to the number/type of arguments you're trying to pass to the `thread` constructor, but I've not really used the std::thread method so I can't help you with that, I'm used to the old fashioned, raw pthread / raw thread model.

Comment: I'll look into atomic and volatile variables. I think I have finished my assignment but could you take a look at it? Also is it using mutual exclusion? I think it might be and it's not supposed to but I'm not that confident in what MX is. I uploaded my code to pastebin. I hope that's okay. Thanks again for all of your wonderful help!

http://pastebin.com/7fGvjRE0

Comment: @Carl I assume it works currently?  I've made some comments here: http://pastebin.com/1rzZDd9J It is using MX, but you have two shared resources (the file and the console), so you need to protect them somehow.  It isn't using the proper thread coordination classes though.  Using variables like 'vowFlag' without having them volatile can be risky, because the compiler may choose to cache the value in a register (meaning that you never exit the while loop), however compilers are pretty clever about this nowadays so it may not be necessary.

Comment: @Carl Non-atomic variables may also risk dirty reads (where one thread reads whilst another is writing to a variable), however the risk should be fairly low with the current approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
void cons(std::string currWord){...}
void vow(std::string currWord){...}
bool checkVowel(std::string word) {...}
```

For potentially expensive to copy parameters like `std::string`, prefer to pass them by reference (to `const` if immutable).

Be consistent with your spacing, i.e. `){` vs `) {`.

```
void cons(std::string const& currWord) {...}
void vow(std::string const& currWord) {...}
bool checkVowel(std::string const& word) {...}
```

---

```
bool checkVowel(std::string word) {
    char vowels[10] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(word[0] == vowels[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use the least amount of language power to accomplish your task.

If you are only checking if the first character is a vowel, do you need to pass the whole string?

Prefer range-based `for` loops over manually written `for` loops.  Use specialized range functions in `<algorithm>` instead of writing loops yourself.

Qualify immutable variables with `const`.  If the variable represents a constant literal, use `constexpr` instead.

```
constexpr bool isVowel(const char ch) {
    constexpr char vowels[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    for (auto vowel : vowels) {
        if (ch == vowel) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This could be further improved using a compile-time `string_view` (Boost, C++17) to represent your vowels and a `constexpr find` (Boost, Sprout, maybe C++17).

---

```
    std::string currWord;
    std::ifstream input;
    input.open("phrase.txt");
```

Initialize variables as you need them.  C++ does not impose the same restrictions as C89 did.

You can avoid two-step initialization by passing the file you want to open to the constructor.

```
    if(input.is_open()) {
    currWord = std::string();

    while(!input.eof()) {
            input >> currWord;
```

`std::ifstream` objects are [contextually convertible to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).  They are also overloaded for [`operator!`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!).

`input.eof()` does not predict when you will reach end-of-file.  It's purpose is to tell you if it has attempted to read past the end of the file.  The simplest solution is to check if the stream was successfully read from (`while (input >> word)`).

```
    std::ifstream input{"phrase.txt"};
    if (!input) {
        std::cerr << "Error: File not found.";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (std::string current_word; input >> current_word; ) { /* ... */ }
```

---

```
        if(checkVowel(currWord)) { /* ... */ }
        else { /* ... */ }
```

The problem asks you to print words beginning with consonants or vowels.  You've assumed that words can only begin with only those two, but what about words that begin with a digit? A symbol?

---

Your method works, but it's not really concurrent.  As Forsvarir mentioned, [there are different approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm#See_also) to the critical section problem in concurrent programming.  Pick one and implement it.

As for the use of [`std::this_thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield), your host environment determines whether you should use it. See the note on the reference page:

> The exact behavior of this function depends on the implementation, in particular on the mechanics of the OS scheduler in use and the state of the system. For example, a first-in-first-out real time scheduler (`SCHED_FIFO` in Linux) would suspend the current thread and put it on the back of the queue of the same-priority threads that are ready to run (and if there are no other threads at the same priority, yield has no effect).